# IndexError: list index out of range error python

Tags: python

here is my simple python code. I could not figure out why  its shows index out of range .any help .

```
distances = []
i=0
for i in range(len(points)):
    point = points[i]
    next_point = points[i+1]
    x0 = point[0]
    y0 = point[1]        
    x1 = next_point[0]
    y1 = next_point[1]       
    point_distance = get_distance(x0, y0, x1, y1)        
    distances.append(point_distance)
```

Comment: What is `points`? What line gives the index out of range error?

Comment: next_point = points[i+1] line gives the error  points is the list of coordinate vales

Comment: next_point = points[i+1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe it's the fact that you're using `points[i+1]`. When you reach the last position of `points` (`points[i]`) the `i+1` will try to access a position that does not exists. You need to check if you're in the last position before getting the next point or limit your `for` cycle to: `len(points) - 1`